# Prevent R from updating automatically

Tags: r, rgui

I'm currently using R via the command line in another software. Apparently, R automatically upgrades it version from time to time resulting in a new installation of R in different location.
After that, packages have to be reinstalled and the path to the R executable has to be changed. The software I'm using requires a fixed path to R.

Is there a way to prevent R from updating automatically? 
I'm running R on Windows 10.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Never heard of R updating automatically on Windows. It requires running an installer with user input unless you have created a different build system, which I doubt. What you usually see on Windows systems are extremely outdated R versions because the user doesn't update.

Comment: Mh.. thanks for the hint. Do you know of a way to figure out, which user/service might have triggered the installation? I couldn't find any installation logs so far. Happened to me multiple times so far and I don't know why.

Comment: Are you the system admin?

Comment: yes, I have administrative rights.

Comment: But are you the system admin? Or is there someone else updating R? Because I'm telling you it usually doesn't happen automatically.